# fread() array of integers from a bin file

Tags: c, arrays, fread, bin

I want to read the content of a binary file, and store it into an array. The binary file has a set number of integers and I need to read it from a specific position untill a set number of integers are stored in the array.

```
int array[atoi(argv[1])] ;   
for (i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]);i++){
            array[i] = rand() %100;
            printf(" %d ", array[i]);
        } // Creates an array filled with random numbers

        fp = fopen("array","w+");
        fwrite(array, sizeof(array), sizeof(array), fp);
        fclose(fp); // Creates the bin file and close it.

// In this example the bin file has 20 integers, and I want to read from the 5th integer till the 16th integer
    int b[15]; 
    int i;
    FILE *fl;
    fl = fopen("array","rb");
    fseek(fl, 5, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        fread(&b[i], sizeof(int),1, fl);
        fl++;
        printf(" %d ", b[i]);
    }
```

At the end I should have all the integers stored in the b array in each cell but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You're writing too much in your `fwrite()` call. It should be `fwrite(array, sizeof(array), 1, fp);`.

Comment: You don't need the loop. You can use the `nitems` argument to `fread()` to read multiple integers in one call.

Comment: When you say the 5th integer, does your indexing start from 0 or 1? If you are thinking 1st, 2nd..., 5th, then you have to use `fseek(fl, 4 * sizeof ( int), SEEK_SET);`

Comment: followed your comments and got it working, thanks. @Barman if you could expand on how to use nitems I could add it to my code

Comment: A little warning: If your file is to be read by computers with different architecture than it was written by, the result may be wrong. For example, bit length of integers may differ, and so may bit order (endian-ness).